# Android, what happens to Listview if IME pops up?

Tags: android, listview, ime

I have a listview inside a fragment. When IME pops up the listview is resized, but I want to know what happens in code behind for that listview. As for what I have observed the listview's `notifydatasetchanged()` method is not called because it will refresh the listview but this is not the state here. The only thing I see is that the view of the list item is updated not the whole listview.

Could anyone clarify whats happening to the listview?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have adjustResize as your softInputMode, the entire window is resized, causing a relayout to happen. Any scrollable containers are adjusted so that the focused view is visible. If you have adjustPan, the window is only moved, but not resized.

None of this has anything to do with data. In fact, in both cases the view doesn't even need to requery the adapter since either its size is getting smaller (it will discard views), or its size will be exactly the same, just off screen.

What are you trying to achieve that you're asking this question?

Comment: I'm trying to know what is happened in code behind. I could look in source code but I didnt know where to begin.
Btw I have found out my solution. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Answer (Im low repped):
I updated the wrong Adapter which was the `PagerAdapter` instead of the list item `SimpleCursorAdapter`. So `notifyDataSetChanged()` was the right one to use.

But you are right, it has nothing to do with data, but the view (list items) is updated.

Comment: For the said question Delyan's answer is correct. That should be accepted as the answer. Your answer is irrelevant to the question itself.